# My application creates separate SQL database on Azure

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

I have an web app has two database connections.

One is default connection which is used for Identity Models.

They both uses the same database in local development environment and it works fine.

However when I publish to Azure and log in to application, Identity Model creates separate S1 standard tier SQL database when I run the application.
(different database name with 465 in the end of name)

It uses same connection strings. In .pubxml I have...

```
 <ObjectGroup Name="TrackingEntities" Order="1" Enabled="False">
      <Destination Path="Data Source=tcp:name.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=name;User ID=admin@name;Password=mypass" Name="Data Source=tcp:name.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=name;User Id=admin@name;Password=mypass" />
      <Object Type="DbCodeFirst">
        <Source Path="DBContext" DbContext="TimeClock.TrackingEntities, TimeClock" Origin="Configuration" />
      </Object>
```

How do I prevent from creating new SQL database and uses the one I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, web deployment via VS doesn't overwrite Azure's settings.
Therefore it didn't change DefaultConnection string in Azure. 
(Is it different from app's default connection?)
I went to Connection strings under application setting in Asure portal and it had wrong Initial Catalog name. So application was creating the SQL database.